# Auto Layout: Position a table on top of an image using proportional spacing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, autolayout

I'm trying to add an `UITableView` on top of an image but inside a "rectangle" of that image. The image's size is relative to its parent view.

Here is the image at the back and the table view should be inside the brown area.

**Back Image:**

[image: Back image]

I tried Proportional Spacing by setting the Top property of the table to the Bottom of the image and using a multiplier.
Did the same by setting the Leading property of the table to the Right of the image.

It almost work on iPhones, but when I switch to the iPad, the top of the table is much lower than the brown rect.

Here are some screenshots:

**iPhone 7:**

[image: iPhone 7]

**iPad:**

[image: iPad]

I've been struggling to fix this issue and couldn't find any way to do it.

Do you think there is a way to fix this?

Thank you :)

Comment: Are the images same size, or are the created with different size and aspect ratio?

Comment: I'm using the same image for all devices and it's being stretched depending on the device's screen.

Comment: Always use aspect ratio for uiimageview, its for making sure it will result in correct size, this here seems like you only pin them but not giving aspect ratio, if you really must stretch the image then use slicing

Comment: @tj3n I tried giving an aspect ratio to the image, but it doesn't fix the main issue. Because the space between the top of the image and the top of the brown area is not the same. It depends on the height of the image.

Comment: If you having a problem with top header thing, you can set the "ContentInset" for top

Comment: @Wolverine Will it help? I can't know the value of the ContentInset.

Comment: @JosephELKHOURY it should fix the issue, since you have aspect ratio, it will scale both width and height of the image isnt it, then it will look smaller but still correct

Comment: @Tj3n the problem is not with the image being stretched or not. The problem is with the table view that is on top of it that should be located exactly inside the brown area of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Set the alignment rect on the image to the inside and then autolayout will be much easier

Comment: Is the image in an asset catalog?

Comment: This post has some good info: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/auto-layout-and-alignment-rectangles/